# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Architecture' from assembly 'netstandard'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I created a .NET Standard 2.0 library and referenced the same in .NET core 2.0 Web API. Its gets built successfully without any errors but upon running, it throws an exception at `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` in the following code :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
      // Throws exception here.  
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Exception:

`"Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Architecture' from assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'."`

My .NET Standard Libraries uses the following nuget packages:

- StackExchange.Redis
- RabbitMQ.Client
- Newtonsoft.Json
- Google.Protobuf.Tools
- Google.Protobuf
- Grpc.Tools
- Grpc.Core
- Grpc.Auth
- System.Data.SqlClient

I tried the following links but none of them helped me.

- https://github.com/ironmansoftware/universal-dashboard/issues/79
- https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/328

**However, the API runs fine without any exception if not referenced the above library.**

Comment: "a .NET Standard 2.0 library" - why not a Core library, or the normal Core project (exe) ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried that and it worked.Weird it doesn't work using .NET standard.I used NET standard initially to support both .NET framework 4.5+ and .NET core.For now I only need for .NET core so it is sufficient indeed for now. Thanks for asking that question though.

Comment: Do you have a repro where you are seeing the exception? I would like to understand why you are seeing that.

Comment: @AlexGhiondea-MSFT I will try to re-create that with a sample project and will revert.

Comment: I am having this same issue.  It happened when I added library sourced from VSTS.  When I remove those packages it starts working.
I am targeting `netcorapp2.0` and all my packages are targeting `netstandard2.0`

I found the same issues as @shubhamr is there any suggested resolution for this?

Comment: @RodneyLittles In my case it was only dotnet core apps consuming this library, hence I changed the target version to dotnet core instead of dotnet standard and it worked.You can do the same if it suits your case for the workaround.Don't know the fix for the standard version yet.

Comment: @shubhamr I believe I figured out a resolution to my problem.  With all the package management fun, I'm not sure exactly what the problem was.  One of my packages had a dependency that was somehow getting a legacy reference.  I removed that package so that all references where `netstandard2.0` and everything worked.  I was attempting to build `netstandard` libraries for use in a `netcoreapp` and somehow got a legacy framework reference tangled in.